# Adding Array of Markers in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need some help in creating an array of markers in Google Map so that it can be more efficient, instead of create a marker one by one. I tried the following but it doesn't work. Anyone have advice?

```
//create array to store a set of location
var collection = new Array();

//a set of locations stored in array
collection[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(13.742167701649997, 100.50721049308777);
collection[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(13.74428, 100.5404525);
collection[2] = new google.maps.LatLng(13.744108, 100.543098);

var pointMarkerImage = new Array();//store image of marker in array
var pointMarker = new Array();//store marker in array

//create number of markers based on collection.length
function setPoint(){
for(var i=0; i<collection.length; i++){

var pointMarkerImage[i] = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker.png');
var pointMarker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: collection[i],
        map: map,
        icon: pointMarkerImage[i],
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        title: "collection"+ i 
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(pointMarker[i], 'click', function()    { 
             window.open("blog/page01.html","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=yes")
             };
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you are invoking `setPoint()`? Where do you call this function?

Comment: haven´t you thought of a for loop, you dont need to create a new latlng object for each array index, you can just store the number and do for(tipical for){ new google.map.(lat[i])} something like that

Comment: thanks for your comments, i might need to post the whole code to give a proper look below..

Answer (score 38):

This is my simple code and it works fine. When you click on marker, it will open the Info Window respectively based on that marker's location.

```
<script>
var locations = [
     ['Title A', 3.180967,101.715546, 1],
     ['Title B', 3.200848,101.616669, 2],
     ['Title C', 3.147372,101.597443, 3],
     ['Title D', 3.19125,101.710052, 4]
];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 12,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.171368,101.653404),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
         return function() {
             infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
    })(marker, i));
}
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="map_result">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>Multiple Marker</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content" style="padding:0;">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That function(i) returning function thing is very nifty.

Comment: related to this approach, ie how to remove markers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286913/google-maps-setmap-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 4):

I see a few things:

1) in the for loop, var pointM... should just be pointM... adding the var makes it ignore the set you have outside the for loop.

2) you have a ; after a function that is breaking things.

Try this:

```
//create array to store a set of location
var collection = new Array();

//a set of locations stored in array
collection[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(13.742167701649997, 100.50721049308777);
collection[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(13.74428, 100.5404525);
collection[2] = new google.maps.LatLng(13.744108, 100.543098);

var pointMarkerImage = new Array();//store image of marker in array
var pointMarker = new Array();//store marker in array

//create number of markers based on collection.length
function setPoint(){
  for(var i=0; i<collection.length; i++){

    pointMarkerImage[i] = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker.png');
    pointMarker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: collection[i],
            map: map,
            icon: pointMarkerImage[i],
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            title: "collection"+ i 
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(pointMarker[i], 'click', function(){
      window.open("blog/page01.html","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=yes");
    }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It was a careless mistake! Not sure why it is still not working. i might want to post the whole code below to give a better picture.

Answer (score 2):

I copied Mr Qiqi Abaziz and improved a bit. This is full version

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initMap() {

    var locations = [
         ['Title A', 3.180967,101.715546],
         ['Title B', 3.200848,101.616669],
         ['Title C', 3.147372,101.597443],
         ['Title D', 3.19125,101.710052]
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 12,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.171368,101.653404),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
             map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
             return function() {
                 infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
             }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}

</script>

<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=YOURAPIKEY=initMap">
</script>


<style type="text/css">
  #map { height: 400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:left;
    width: 80%;}
</style>

<div id="map"></div>
```