# Retrieving GPS Coordinates with addListener(dragend) When Map is Redrawn to Find Address

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to retrieve GPS coordinates from the last place the customer drags a moveable Pin.

If the customer uses the original Pin, I can retrieve the coordinates, but if the customer types in an address, say "321 Elk Road, Page, AZ, USA", I cannot retrieve the coordinates.

I have used a combination of suggestions from [JavaScript API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) and this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921922/1422252).

```
 /* JavaScript */
function initAutocomplete() {

  var uluru = {lat: 36.8737979, lng: -111.510586};
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
   document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 6
   , center: uluru});

   
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: uluru,
   map: map,
   draggable:true,
   title:"Drag me!"
 });

// This addListener works:

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
  document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
  document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});


// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


// Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
map.addListener("bounds_changed", function() {
  searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});

  var newMarkers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
   searchBox.addListener("places_changed", function() {
   var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

if (places.length == 0) {
  return;
}

// Clear out the old markers.
newMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
  marker.setMap(null);
});
newMarkers = [];

// For each place, get the icon, name and location.
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
places.forEach(function(place) {
  if (!place.geometry) {
    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }
  var icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  // Create a marker for each place.
  newMarkers.push(
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      draggable:true,
     title: "Drag Me!",
      position: place.geometry.location
    })
  );

  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    // Only geocodes have viewport.
    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }

  // This addListener does not work:
   
  google.maps.event.addListener(newMarkers, 'dragend', (function(marker, i) {
       return function() {
       document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
       document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
       }
  })(marker, i));

});

map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PhillipOReilly/zptwb7oL/20/).

I think I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error in the console of your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PhillipOReilly/zptwb7oL/20/): `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined` because `i` isn't defined on this line: `})(marker, i));`

The other issue is you are trying to add the event listener to an array, that doesn't work, you have to add it to the individual markers:

```
  searchBox.addListener("places_changed", function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    newMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    newMarkers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Drag Me!",
        position: place.geometry.location
      })
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
      });
      newMarkers.push(marker);
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
```

Note that this code will leave the original marker, you may want to remove that so you only ever have that marker or the markers from the last search on the map at a given time.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cjhbgyv5/1/)

[image: screenshot of map after dragging marker from search]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {

  var uluru = {
    lat: 36.8737979,
    lng: -111.510586
  };
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: uluru
    });
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: "Drag me!"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
  });


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener("bounds_changed", function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var newMarkers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener("places_changed", function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    newMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    newMarkers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Drag Me!",
        position: place.geometry.location
      })
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
      });
      newMarkers.push(marker);
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });


    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div */

#map {
  height: 400px;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* width */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Places Search Box</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>


  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="¿A dónde lo llevamos?">

  <table width="95%" height=5 0% border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tbody>
      <!-- Begin Second Class -->
      <tr>
        <td>

          <div id="map"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="latlong">
    <p>Latitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat"> &nbsp Longitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="lngbox" name="lng"></p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```