# Google Maps Markers marker.setMap(null) not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I know this question seems similar to a lot of others.

Following problem. I save Google Maps markers with an array.

If I want to update them I am not able to write marker.set(**Something**). I have to write marker.j.map = null;

- Did I miss something?

e.g.

```js
var markers = [];

function doAddMarkers(){
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
           [...]
    }).addListener('click', (function (i) {
           [...]
    }).bind(this, "xxx"), false));
}

function DoStartHl(pElement) {
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  if (pElement !== i && markers[i].j.animation !== null) {
   markers[i].j.animation = null;
  }
 }
 if (markers[parseInt(pElement.id)].j.animation === null) {
 markers[parseInt(pElement.id)].j.animation = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
 }
}
```

**Update**

The solution is to add a `.j.` between the current marker and the setter.

Comment: You are iterating over the array of markers using the index.  So, `marker` is not defined.  You should reference the marker by its index in the markers array...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a StackOverflow code snippet.

Comment: @geocodezip Does it look better now?

Comment: Doesn't look like a [mcve] to me.  [create a stack snippet that demonstrates your issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the array of markers using the index. So, marker is not defined. You should reference the marker by its index in the markers array

```
function DoClearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].j.map = null;
    markers[i].map = null;
    // marker.setMap(null); <= Won't work. ".setMap() is not a function"
    //the above won't work because `marker` is not defined.
    //instead, reference the marker by its index in the array:

    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I added the marker with markers[markser.lenght] = marker;

Comment: @GreilOmatics - so inspect what you have within your iteration... and define "not working" -- same error or ???

Comment: I added the console output for the array. Does this help you

Comment: perhaps `markers[i].j.setMap(null)` ?? It's really hard to say with what you've given us.  It's not clear what you want to do.  However, my answer above should resolve your error, no?

Comment: I tried in debug console. setMap is not a function.

Comment: @GreilOmatics ok, then that suggests you don't actually have markers in your markers array.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286913/google-maps-setmap-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Ok, markers[i].j.setMap() is a function. So, there was a change. Now the '.j.' is new. pushing as in my example is allowed.